# access pyodbc object in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

Probably a naive question but any pointers would be appreciated.

I am trying to connect to my database and then trying to put the data in the pandas dataframe. However I am not able to achieve the same.

Here is the code that I am trying :

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
server = ''
    database = ''
    username = ''
    password = ''
    driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
    connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';PORT=1433;SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    Query = "SELECT * from database"

    cursor.execute(Query)
    df = Dataframe(cursor.fetchall())
    df.columns = resoverall.keys()
    print(df)
```

I am getting this error

> df = Dataframe(cursor.fetchall()) NameError: global name 'Dataframe'
>   is not defined

Can anyone suggest what wrong am I doing here.

Comment: pd.DataFrame() is the correct syntax.

Comment: @wich I tried it, but it still gives the same error 

df = DataFrame(cursor.fetchall()) NameError: global name 'DataFrame' is not defined

Comment: You are missing the pd in pd.DataFrame.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())

Comment: @Atendra Thanks this works.. Although can you also advice as to how do we assign column names as well to the df in the similar scenario

Answer (score 0):

`df = pd.Dataframe(cursor.fetchall(),columns=resoverall.keys())`

Answer (score 0):

pandas already has a [read_sql_query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html) method to achieve what you describe:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(Query, connection)
```